# Как реализовать такую кнопку, чтоб она следовала за курсором, когда мышь рядом?

Tags: javascript, frontend

Как можно реализовать такую кнопку как на этом сайте (надпись - let's go!), которая следует за курсором, если курсор рядом?
https://www.cloudmill.ru/contacts/
Желательно на чистом JS ну или на jQuery.

Comment: Просто скопировать необходимый код, раз есть уже готовое и нужно также.

Comment: Там сложный код..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как-то так.

`offset` это расстояние от центра элемента, при котором будет происходить "разрыв" примагничивания.

```js
let offset = 50, cur = false;

document.body.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
  if(e.target.classList.contains('magnetic') && cur === false) {
    cur = {
        e: e.target,
      x: e.target.getBoundingClientRect().left,
      y: e.target.getBoundingClientRect().top
    };
  }
}, true);

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    if(cur !== false) {
    let x = (e.clientX - cur.x) - (cur.e.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2),
            y = (e.clientY - cur.y) - (cur.e.getBoundingClientRect().height / 2);
    cur.e.style.transform = `translate(${x}px,${y}px)`;
    //
    if(Math.abs(x) >= offset || Math.abs(y) >= offset) {
        cur.e.style.transform = 'translate(0,0)';
      cur = false;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.magnetic {
  transition: transform .2s linear;
}
```

```html
<button class="magnetic">Magnet button</button>
```