# Как сделать кнопку, которая будет тянуться за мышкой

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать кнопку, которая сразу стоит на месте, но если на нее навести и попробовать увести в сторону, то кнопка пойдет за мышкой, вот пример на сайте(белая кнопка со стрелочкой): https://www.m-trust.co.jp/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так.

`offset` это расстояние от центра элемента, при котором будет происходить "разрыв" примагничивания.

```js
let offset = 50, cur = false;

document.body.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
  if(e.target.classList.contains('magnetic') && cur === false) {
    cur = {
        e: e.target,
      x: e.target.getBoundingClientRect().left,
      y: e.target.getBoundingClientRect().top
    };
  }
}, true);

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    if(cur !== false) {
    let x = (e.clientX - cur.x) - (cur.e.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2),
            y = (e.clientY - cur.y) - (cur.e.getBoundingClientRect().height / 2);
    cur.e.style.transform = `translate(${x}px,${y}px)`;
    //
    if(Math.abs(x) >= offset || Math.abs(y) >= offset) {
        cur.e.style.transform = 'translate(0,0)';
      cur = false;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.magnetic {
  transition: transform .2s linear;
}
```

```html
<button class="magnetic">Magnet button</button>
```

---

Ответ скопирован с вопроса [Как реализовать такую кнопку, чтоб она следовала за курсором, когда мышь рядом? [закрыт]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1267212/221218)

Answer (score 0):

Почитай про [MouseEvent client Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_clientx.asp), [MouseEvent screen Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_screenx.asp) и  [MouseEvent offset Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_offsetx.asp)

Пример:

```
 let x = event.screenX; //достает положение мышки относительно экрана
 let y = event.screenY;
 let cord = "X: " + x + ", Y: " + y;
```

Answer (score 0):

Сам искал. Вот, что используется на указанном сайте:
https://codepen.io/riogrande/pen/bxmLYm

```js
function buttonHoverAnimation() {
  // Get all button elements
  const buttonSelector = document.querySelectorAll(".button");

  // Loop through all button elements
  for (let i = 0; i < buttonSelector.length; i++) {
    // Get text inside of a button wrapped in span
    const buttonTextSelector = buttonSelector[i].querySelector("span");

    function mousemoveFn(event) {
      // Get X-coordinate for the left button edge
      const buttonPos = event.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect().left;

      // Get position of the mouse inside element from left edge
      // (current mouse X position - button x coordinate)
      const xPosOfMouse = event.clientX - buttonPos;

      // Get position of mouse relative to button center
      // Mouse position inside element - button width / 2
      // To get positive or negative movement
      const xPosOfMouseInsideButton =
        xPosOfMouse - buttonSelector[i].offsetWidth / 2;

      // Button text divider to increase or decrease text path
      const animationDivider = 3;

      console.log(xPosOfMouseInsideButton);

      // Animate button text positive or negative from center
      TweenMax.to(buttonTextSelector, 2, {
        x: xPosOfMouseInsideButton / animationDivider,
        ease: Power3.easeOut
      });
    }

    // On mouse leave
    function mouseleaveFn() {
      // Animate button text reset to initial position (center)
      TweenMax.to(buttonTextSelector, 1, {
        x: 0,
        ease: Power3.easeOut
      });
    }

    buttonSelector[i].addEventListener("mousemove", mousemoveFn);

    buttonSelector[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", mouseleaveFn);
  }
}

buttonHoverAnimation();
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 75px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
}

button::before {
  content: "";
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

button:hover::before {
  transform: scaleY(0.9);
}

button span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.4/gsap.min.js"></script>
<button class="button">
<span>Button text</span>
</button>
```